# What is the I symbol in probability?

Tags: probability, summation, random-variables

I have a question from an exercise sheet where $T$ is a discrete random variable and assuming that $T$ takes values in $\mathbb{N}$, I need to show that $\mathbb{E}[T]=\sum_{t=0}^\infty\mathbb{P}(T>t)$. 
 The question tells me to use a hint which is to consider $\sum_{t=0}^\infty\mathbb{I}[T>t].$ Does $\mathbb{I}$ mean an indicator random variable? I haven't come across this before.

Comment: yes, it's an indicator r.v.

Comment: Thanks. How could I us that hint to get to that answer? And am I right in saying an indicator r.v can only take the values 0 and 1?

Comment: You want to show that $T = \sum \mathbb{I}[T > t]$, then take the expectation of both sides.

Comment: Would you have that $\sum_{t=0}^\infty\mathbb{I}[T>t]=\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}1=T$

Comment: Thanks @QiaochuYuan I understand now

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need to use Fubini/Tonelli's theorem.

$$P(T> k)=\sum_{t=k+1}^{\infty}P(T=t)$$

So $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(T> k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{t=k+1}^{\infty}P(T=t)$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{\{t> k\}}P(T=t)$$.

Now interchange the order of summation using Fubini/Tonelli (As summands are positive)

$$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{\{t> k\}}P(T=t)=\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}P(T=t)=\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}tP(T=t),$$

since $\mathbf{1}_{\{t> k\}}=0$ for $k\geq t$.

So we have $$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}tP(X=T)=\mathbb{E}[X]$$.

If you know a bit of measure theory, then actually this is true more generally in that given any non-negative random variable $X$, you have $$E[X]=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X>t)\,dt$$ .  and it gives us a way to talk about expectation only in terms of the CDF.

Comment: Thanks I have not covered Fubini/Tonelli theorem but it was well explained. So you can only interchange the summations in they are both positive? And why does the original answer not suffice?

Comment: Fubini's theorem tells that if the double summation $\sum_{m,n}f(m,n)$ exists then you can write $\sum_{m}\sum_{n}f(m,n)=\sum_{n}\sum_{m}f(m,n)$ that is evaluate one by one in any order. Tonelli's theorem gives that if the summands are positive, then you can always interchange the order of summation regardless of whether it exists. Also what "original answer" ? You have not proved anything. In order to have $E[T]=E[\sum_{t\geq 0}\mathbb{I}[T>t]]=\sum_{t\geq 0} E\mathbb{I}[T>t]]=\sum_{t\geq 0}P(T>t)$ , notice that you ARE changing the order of summation to move the expectation inside.

Comment: That "exchange" of summation and expectation(which is also a summation in this case) is what I have explicitly justified.